# JavaScript function calls within Django form fields

Tags: javascript, django

I'd like to create a form where I have checkboxes, and when clicked, they open separate textareas for the user to enter more information in.

If I want to use Django's dynamically created form fields, is there a way that I can put a function call in for each checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically add event handlers using JavaScript. You can add a script that, once the page is loaded, will find all checkboxes you want and add the handlers there. In [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can write something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my_form input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
          //Some code here
    });
});
```

Be careful, I have not tested the code above! But should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, that should be enough to get me started.