# using javascript in a django template

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I have a working javascript file that adds and removes check boxes and drop down lists on an html page using the element ID tag. I would like to apply the javascript code to a form that is being generated by a django app. I have tried to hide a field by changing the javascript element ID as follows,

```
id1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

to match an element on the form that is being generated by django but the javascript isn't taking effect and the field is still visible.

In my django template html file, I have included the js file from the site that is being served up by django.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/submitform.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
```

I can see in the template page source code the js file as above and can click on the link and see the javascript code. So I know the javascript file is contained within the template.

I have done something similar with my css file and that takes effect on the template page, however I can't get the javascript to apply correctly.

I've been struggling with this for a while now and haven't done this before. Can anyone provide help or know of any documentation that I can read which shows me how to do this?

Sorry if this isn't an appropriate question but haven't done this before and I am just stuck on this.. The project I am working on is for an internal test site so I am not worried at the moment about compressing the js file to the client or any injections that I could be exposed to.. Just getting an understanding how to do this.!

Thanks - Oli

Comment: Why don't you do $('#id1').hide(); ?

Comment: Where would I put that code? I have looked at this post which is what I want to do but not sure where to code this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183796/javascript-function-calls-within-django-form-fields

Comment: Exactly how are you calling that JS?

Comment: I thought the javascript was executed when the page was loaded. Perhaps this is the problem? So it needs to be called within the html file?

Comment: If you're hiding or showing fields in response to a checkbox being ticked, what's the point of only running the JS when the page is loaded? Presumably you want it on the `onclick` attribute of the checkbox, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
#html
{% block main-menu %} 
    <br>
    <br>
    Click here to play with username
    <button id="show_button">show</button>
    <button id="hide_button">hide</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $("#show_button").click(function() {
                    $("#id_username").show();
                });
                $("#hide_button").click(function() {
                    $("#id_username").hide();
                });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="contentarea">
        <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ reg_form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
    </div>

#forms.py
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password (Again)", widget=forms.PasswordInput())

Here your clean methods and so on
```

Django will automatically create an id for your fields like id_yourfield.

Comment: Thanks Serg for taking the time out and answering my question. that's got me on my way.. Together with this http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works I have enough to get an understanding on how it all works.. I knew that django creates the ID's for me so I am using firebug to determine these and appending the jquery code to get my desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Include the Jquery library before including your jquery file , so swap it to this:

```
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/submitform.js"></script>
</head>
```

EDIT:

Also the "type" property is missing in your script tag for jquery Library. I have updated the code, have a look.

Comment: Also the "type" property is missing in your script tag for jquery Library. I have updated the code, have a look.

Comment: @Amyth You do not need to specify the type property if the script is of type "text/javascript" as per the HTML 5 standard.